# How to expose a kubernetes service to all regions in the VPC but not to the outside world

Tags: networking, kubernetes, tcp, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to make a Kubernetes service which is reachable from all regions in my VPC but unreachable from outside.
I've seen that there is the annotation: "cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"" which creates a regional Load Balancer for the service.

I was thinking about creating a TCP proxy VM in the same region as the Kubernetes cluster.
Does anybody know a way to route requests from all the VPC into the Load Balancer or an easy way to create a TCP proxy?

Comment: If you created a VPC-native cluster, you already have the ability to access the cluster from anywhere in your VPC: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips

Comment: If you define a Kubernetes service LoadBalancer/Internal then, as you say, a stable VPC IP address will be created for the load balancer.  I'm not clear on your "TCP proxy VM" story ... a VPC is a global and virtual ... I'm not seeing the problem you are trying to solve.  Can you elaborate on what you see as the puzzle?  Maybe expand your questions with more description.

Comment: John is right, VPC-native clusters are accessible from anywhere from the VPC. But your internal LB idea would also work. Regional doesn't mean it is accessible from the same region, but it can send traffic to resources (VMs) in the same region. So, your internal LB still would be accessible from other regions within your VPC.